# Error in installing the amp file in alfresco war file

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I am new to alfresco record management 5.0,extracted the alfresco rm source code from github for customization of unique record identifier.In the pom file, I have uncommented the  amp  and then build and getting the amp file.To install amp file to alfresco war below statement executed.Also I have added the module properties file under the config amp folder

```
java -jar alfresco-mmt.jar install c:\alfresco-one\amps\repo-amp.amp c:\alfresco-one\tomcat\webapps\alfresco.war 
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
Error occured:

de.schlichtherle.truezip.fs.FsEntryNotFoundException: amp:file:/c:/alfresco-one/
amps/alfresco-rm-server-amp.amp!/module.properties (no such entry)
        at de.schlichtherle.truezip.fs.FsBasicArchiveController$1Input.getLocalT
arget(FsBasicArchiveController.java:187)
        at de.schlichtherle.truezip.fs.FsBasicArchiveController$1Input.getDelega
te(FsBasicArchiveController.java:200)
        at de.schlichtherle.truezip.socket.DelegatingInputSocket.getBoundSocket(
DelegatingInputSocket.java:43)
        at de.schlichtherle.truezip.socket.DelegatingInputSocket.newInputStream(
DelegatingInputSocket.java:63)
        at de.schlichtherle.truezip.fs.FsContextController$Input.newInputStream(
FsContextController.java:273)
        at de.schlichtherle.truezip.fs.FsResourceController$Input.newInputStream
(FsResourceController.java:252)
        at de.schlichtherle.truezip.socket.DelegatingInputSocket.newInputStream(
DelegatingInputSocket.java:63)
        at de.schlichtherle.truezip.fs.FsSyncController$Input.newInputStream(FsS
yncController.java:400)
        at de.schlichtherle.truezip.fs.FsLockController$Input$1NewInputStream.ca
ll(FsLockController.java:455)
        at de.schlichtherle.truezip.fs.FsLockController$Input$1NewInputStream.ca
ll(FsLockController.java:452)
        at de.schlichtherle.truezip.fs.FsLockController.locked(FsLockController.
java:328)
        at de.schlichtherle.truezip.fs.FsLockController.writeLocked(FsLockContro
ller.java:268)
        at de.schlichtherle.truezip.fs.FsLockController$Input.newInputStream(FsL
ockController.java:459)
        at de.schlichtherle.truezip.fs.FsFinalizeController$Input.newInputStream
(FsFinalizeController.java:177)
        at de.schlichtherle.truezip.fs.FsFalsePositiveArchiveController$1Input$N
ewInputStream.call(FsFalsePositiveArchiveController.java:333)
        at de.schlichtherle.truezip.fs.FsFalsePositiveArchiveController$1Input$N
ewInputStream.call(FsFalsePositiveArchiveController.java:326)
        at de.schlichtherle.truezip.fs.FsFalsePositiveArchiveController$TryChild
.call(FsFalsePositiveArchiveController.java:507)
        at de.schlichtherle.truezip.fs.FsFalsePositiveArchiveController.call(FsF
alsePositiveArchiveController.java:104)
        at de.schlichtherle.truezip.fs.FsFalsePositiveArchiveController$1Input.n
ewInputStream(FsFalsePositiveArchiveController.java:323)
        at de.schlichtherle.truezip.file.TFileInputStream.newInputStream(TFileIn
putStream.java:104)
        at de.schlichtherle.truezip.file.TFileInputStream.<init>(TFileInputStrea
m.java:81)
        at org.alfresco.repo.module.tool.ModuleDetailsHelper.createModuleDetails
FromPropertyLocation(ModuleDetailsHelper.java:74)
        at org.alfresco.repo.module.tool.ModuleManagementTool.installModule(Modu
leManagementTool.java:220)
        at org.alfresco.repo.module.tool.ModuleManagementTool.main(ModuleManagem
entTool.java:813)
01200001 An error was encountered during deployment of the AMP into the WAR: 012
00000 Unable to load module details from property file. File Not Found, amp:file
:/c:/alfresco-one/amps/alfresco-rm-server-amp.amp!/module.properties (no such en
try)

Please help to resolve this.Thanks
```

Comment: Could you write the url of the github that you used? Just to be sure that we are using the same version.

Comment: URL :https://github.com/Alfresco/records-management.

Comment: I am also getting the same error when I am applying the amps.I have customize some feature and generate the amp.